# Autodesk Forge tutorials for Model Check App

Tags: visual-studio-code, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360, model-checking

**Hi everyone**

I've started to learn about Autodesk Forge and I'm a beginner in coding.
I've been able to put together the Model 3D Viewer following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FMwgJcRHz8

**My current tusk is:**
to build a WebApp on Forge for model elements naming check based on customisable validation schemas similar to this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxM5TojTmLE
With additional functionality of creating a BIM360 issue for every mismatch fond by checker, like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9EgshGh2is

**My questions are:**

- Is there any learning paths or educational platform that I can use to achieve my goals on this?
- Can you please share any relevant experience?

**Any advices would be highly appreciated**

P.S: I know about this one already:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/?id=learn-autodesk-forge

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can check the object names in two ways:

#### Option 1: Translate your designs with Forge & check the conversion output

The [Forge Model Derivative service](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview) can extract all sorts of information (3D geometry, 2D drawings, property metadata, design hierarchies, etc.) from over 60 different design file formats, incl. Revit. The extracted data can then be viewed in Forge Viewer, or explored using various endpoints or through SDKs for specific programming language. In your case you could use the [GET :urn/metadata/:guid](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET) endpoint to retrieve the design hierarchy which includes object names.

#### Option 2: Check your designs with custom Revit plugin using Design Automation

If you're familiar with Revit API and plugin development, you could also use the [Forge Design Automation service](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/overview) to process Revit models with your custom plugin remotely, by starting a Revit instance on Autodesk servers.